# Summing two polynomials

Tags: matlab, sum, polynomial-math, built-in

I'm looking for a built-in Matlab function that sums two polynomial.

Example:

[image: \ p_1(x) = 500x^5 + 400x^4 + 300x^3 + 200x^2 + 100x + 50 \ p_2(x) = \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\, 3x^3 + \quad 2x^2 + \quad\;\, x + \;\; 5 \ p_s(x) = 500x^5 + 400x^4 + 303x^3 + 202x^2 + 101x + 55]

p1(x) and p2(x) are represented in code standard Matlab vectors:

```
p1 = [500 400 300 200 100 50];
p2 = [3 2 1 5];
```

How do I sum these two polynomials to get ps(x) with using built-in Matlab function(s); without writing an explicit m-file function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sure hope there is a nicer way of doing it (I'd probably put this into a helper function), but this seems to work just fine:

```
[zeros(1, size(p1,2)-size(p2,2)) p2] + [zeros(1, size(p2,2)-size(p1,2)) p1]

ans =

   500   400   303   202   101    55
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Write a little function, call it leftpadz.

```
leftpadz = @(p1,p2) [zeros(1,max(0,numel(p2) - numel(p1)))),p1];
```

So if we have...

```
p1 = [500 400 300 200 100 50];
p2 = [3 2 1 5];
p3 = leftpadz(p1,p2) + leftpadz(p2,p1)
p3 =
   500   400   303   202   101    55
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function c = polyadd( a, b)
assert( isrow(a))
assert( isrow(b))

maxL = max( [length(a), length(b)]);
a = [ zeros( 1, maxL - length(a)), a];
b = [ zeros( 1, maxL - length(b)), b];

c = a +b ;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
p1 = [500 400 300 200 100 50];
p2 = [0 0 3 2 1 5]; # refilling with 0

ps = p1 + p2;
```

Comment: p2 is dynamically created in the code. I can not add zeroes in that way.

Comment: Sorry, but .+ is NOT even a valid a matlab operator. + is all you need.

Comment: You're right, I tested it in Octave and it worked (I mixed it up with .*)