# Is it possible to find a block for multi-input single-output transfer function in Matlab simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, transfer-function

I have a system with two inputs and one common output.

Let inputs be in1, in2 and output - out.

So I have two transfer functions: out / in1, out / in2.

Using simulink I can use transfer fcn block for each transfer function and then sum their outputs to get a desired output.

But is it possible to join transfer functions out/in1, out/in2 somehow together and to use some simulink block to avoid summation of transfers functions outputs?

Thank you for your time and help in advance!

```
% in symbolic

syms Ht s D K Hg

TF1 = tf([D K],[4*Hg*Ht (2*Hg*D+2*Ht*D) (2*Hg*K+2*Ht*K) 0]);

TF2 = tf([-2*Ht -D -K],[4*Hg*Ht (2*Hg*D+2*Ht*D) (2*Hg*K+2*Ht*K) 0]);

% or in numerical way

Ht = 2.2667;
Hg = 0.92952;
D = 2.29;
K = 1.0216;

TF1 = tf([D K],[4*Hg*Ht (2*Hg*D+2*Ht*D) (2*Hg*K+2*Ht*K) 0]);

TF2 = tf([-2*Ht -D -K],[4*Hg*Ht (2*Hg*D+2*Ht*D) (2*Hg*K+2*Ht*K) 0]);
```

Comment: You can not avoid summing them, but you can hide that operation if you want, just create a custom block with the 2 transfers and the sum inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a really simple solution for this. Given two transfer functions `TF1=tf(num1,den1)` and `TF2=tf(num2,den2)`, the sum `TF1+TF2` can be expressed as a single transfer function `tf(num1*den2+num2*den1,den1*den2)`.

For actual implementation, you will want to use [`conv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) to compute the numerator and denominator polynomials from the polynomial coefficient vectors from the component transfer functions.

```
num = polyadd(conv(num1,den2),conv(num2,den1));
den = conv(den1,den2);
```

Note `polyadd` is not a built-in Matlab function but you can write your own or use https://stackoverflow.com/a/55085308.

If you already have the single-input, single-output (SISO) transfer function objects `tf1` and `tf2` in Matlab, you can also get the sum using `tf1+tf2` or by using `parallel(tf1,tf2,1,1,1,1)` (see https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/parallel.html).

#### Why does this work?

You have two transfer functions:

[image: Y_1=\frac{N_1(s)}{D_1(s)}\cdot U]
[image: Y_2=\frac{N_2(s)}{D_2(s)}\cdot U]

and you are interested in the combined system:
[image: Y=Y_1+Y_2=\bigg(\frac{N_1(s)}{D_1(s)}+\frac{N_2(s)}{D_2(s)}\bigg)\cdot U]

which has the the transfer function:

[image: \frac{N_1(s)}{D_1(s)}+\frac{N_2(s)}{D_2(s)}=\frac{N_1(s) \cdot D_2(s) + N_2(s) \cdot D_1(s)}{D_1(s) \cdot D_2(s)}]